# Dispatching an array of objects individually

Tags: reactjs

I'm a passing an Array of objects as payload. When it get passed to the state, it stays as a single array. I wanted to pass the objects individually. How can i do that?

```
//action
const loadRecord = async  => {
    const res = await axios.get('/records?_sort=streak&_order=desc')
    const records = res.
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_RECORD,
      payload: res.data
    })
  }


//reducer

case LOAD_RECORD:
      return {
        ...state,
        records: [...state.records, action.payload]
      }
```

[I'm currently getting this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/586De.png)

I need the pass the objects to the records state not the array. TIA

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs inside your reducer. **you have to spread your payload too.** because your payload is an array.

```
//reducer

case LOAD_RECORD:
      return {
        ...state,
        records: [...state.records, ...action.payload]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spread the `payload` array into the `records` array

```
case LOAD_RECORD:
  return {
    ...state,
    records: [...state.records, ...action.payload]
  }
```